# Why the QFontMetrics::boundingRect() return a wrong size rect?

Tags: qt, paint, qfontmetrics

I'm using Qt4.7.
When I use QFontMetrics to render my text in some situation, I got a wrong width. My code is like this:

```
QFontMetrics fm(QApplication::font());
QRect rc = fm.boundingRect(str);
```

I found that fm.boundingRect(str) always return a fixed rect while the dpi changed.

Comment: It appears to be using the dpi of the primary screen regardless of which screen it's on. Every find a fix for this?